# Rename request: [google-spreadsheet-api] to [google-sheets-api]

Tags: discussion, status-completed, retag-request, synonym-request

Please rename [google-spreadsheet-api](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/google-spreadsheet-api) to [google-sheets-api](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/google-sheets-api).

[See](https://developers.google.com/google-apps/spreadsheets/?hl=en):

[image]

Shortening to [gs-api] (for which there is some precedent) would serve.

Comment: A synonym seems like a good idea (in what direction?)

Comment: The product was renamed "Google Sheets" [in 2012](http://googleforwork.blogspot.com/2012/10/one-click-to-docs-sheets-and-slides.html) and the API updated to match in 2014. Having the official tag be [google-sheets-api] would be the most consistent, with [google-spreadsheet-api] as a synonym for historical reasons.

Comment: Added the synonym as mentioned by @EricKoleda

Comment: @BhargavRao is there any way to port the tag info that was present on the `google-spreadsheet-api` tag? If my memory serves, there was more information on it than is present for the `google-sheets-api` tag info. I feel the usage guideline is OK as-is though.

Comment: @tehhowch done.

Answer (score 6):

After the question was raised, an independent tag [google-sheets-api](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/google-sheets-api) was created. The current situation is that both tags are in use:

- [google-spreadsheet-api](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/google-spreadsheet-api) (<strike>1171</strike> <strike>1446</strike> 1637 questions)
- [google-sheets-api](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/google-sheets-api) (<strike>32</strike> <strike>770</strike> 1332 questions)

So it's no longer just a naming issue: questions already got split between tags with identical meaning. This requires synonymization and merge. The direction of merging seems obvious, since the current name is [Google Sheets API](https://developers.google.com/sheets/).

Comment: Thanks for the reply, unfortunately too late for the rename to be possible. I tried merging, where google-spreadsheet-api would become a synonym of google-sheets-api, but it fails due to a restriction that you can't merge a larger tag into a smaller one if the ratio is greater than 1.25. Any known workarounds?