# Rename tag [google-data-studio] to [google-looker-studio]

Tags: discussion, status-completed, retag-request

Update: Please merge the tag [google-data-studio](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/google-data-studio) and [looker-studio](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/looker-studio).  The tag [looker-studio](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/looker-studio) is the new name of the tool.

Would it make sense to rename the tag [google-data-studio](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/google-data-studio) to [google-looker-studio](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/google-looker-studio) ?
(See in the discussion: No)

Google announced that the tool [Data Studio is renamed to Looker Studio](https://cloud.google.com/blog/products/data-analytics/looker-next-evolution-business-intelligence-data-studio):

> starting today, Data Studio is now Looker Studio

However, the URL of the tool is still `datastudio.google.com` and Google did not do the renaming in the documentation yet. `lookerstudio.google.com` redirects to the datastudio URL.

There is another tag [looker-studio](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/looker-studio), which is used for the same tool since beginning of 2021.

Comment: The [link](https://cloud.google.com/blog/products/data-analytics/looker-next-evolution-business-intelligence-data-studio) you provided fails to load for me. Though *if* the product has been renamed I would suggest that a *new* tag ([[tag:google-looker-studio]]) created, and then [[tag:google-data-studio]] is made a synonym of it.

Comment: @Larnu Thank you for the suggestion of using synonym. I checked the link and it worked. [Here](https://searchengineland.com/google-data-studio-now-known-as-looker-studio-388658#:~:text=Google%20wrote%20%E2%80%9Cstarting%20today%2C%20Data,driven%20decisions%2C%E2%80%9D%20Google%20added.) a news site reporting it also.

Comment: In truth, it might be that I'm at the office and the link is to `cloud.google`, which is very likely to be fully blocked on the firewall.

Comment: Are the two *the same*? If Looker Studio is a new version then maybe not all questions about Data Studio apply to it (and vice versa) if they have different sets of functionality.

Comment: @VLAZ: Data Studio and Looker Studio are the same. Over the last years several features were added to Data Studio. So for today all questions to Data Studio apply to Looker Studio. Google announced that `Looker Studio Pro` will have addition administration tools and so on and a monthly user fee is charged.

Comment: @Larnu: FYI, the "Merge" tool – which is what moderators would use to do this – shows a checkbox to create a synonym from the source tag to the target tag after the merge. (Likewise, the "Create synonym" button shown to mods on the [Tag Synonyms](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/synonyms) page has a corresponding checkbox to merge the source tag into the target tag before creating a synonym.) ...That said I'm refraining from commenting on what should actually be done with the tag.

Comment: Yes, renaming would be fine, as it's the same service, and just a rebranding, though I'd propose using the tag `Looker-Studio` instead of `Google-Looker-Studio`. Also, a couple of points in the question - 1) The URL lookerstudio.google.com currently works as expected, although it redirects to datastudio.google.com 2) The Looker-Studio tag was created on 12 Oct 2022 (after [Google's announcement](https://cloud.google.com/blog/products/data-analytics/looker-next-evolution-business-intelligence-data-studio))

Answer (score 3):

The announcement was yesterday. Google have not updated yet the results for Google Data Studio.

[image]

Also other places, like https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/data-studio are still using "data studio".

I don't think that we should be faster than them. Some established users  might get upset.

---

Fun facts

1. The https://datastudio.google.com UI Help button shows

   > Looker Studio is now Looker Studio.

   Hopefully we will not be doing the same "recursive" references.

---

Related retag-requests due to Google branding / product "substitution"

- [Rename request: [google-spreadsheet-api] to [google-sheets-api]](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/306649/1595451)
- [Rename [google-consumer-surveys] to [google-surveys]](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/336563/1595451)
- [Rename [google-apps-marketplace] tag](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/394343/1595451)
- [Rename [gsuite] to [google-workspace]](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/402071/1595451)
- [Rename tag [google-drive-team-drive] to [google-drive-shared-drive]](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/405030/1595451)

I'm wondering if already exist specific guidelines for cases like these and if we actually need them.

Comment: Yes, while certain links have rebranded, some links still refer to Data Studio while others redirect to the original URL, thus it could be changed in due course (perhaps during the month).

Answer (score 3):

To reiterate, this is the same service, and it's just a name change (thus, what was called *Data Studio* on 11 Oct 2022 was renamed to *Looker Studio* by 12 Oct 2022)

I propose renaming the tag to [looker-studio](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/looker-studio) (instead of [google-looker-studio](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/google-looker-studio)), with [google-data-studio](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/google-data-studio) as a synonym. For future reference, I had created / first tagged [looker-studio](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/looker-studio) on 12 Oct 2022 (after [Google's announcement](https://cloud.google.com/blog/products/data-analytics/looker-next-evolution-business-intelligence-data-studio))

To explain why the *Google* prefix is not required, below are 3 parent companies and their respective Business Intelligence brands:

| Parent Company | Brand (in Business Intelligence) |
| --- | --- |
| Microsoft | Power BI |
| Salesforce | Tableau |
| Google | Looker |

The current tags for the respective Business Intelligence services do not use the parent company as a prefix (for Power BI and Tableau), thus *Looker* does not need the prefix, *Google*:

| Power BI | Tableau | Looker |
| --- | --- | --- |
| [powerbi](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/powerbi) | [tableau](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/tableau) | [looker](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/looker) |
| [powerbi-desktop](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/powerbi-desktop) | [tableau-desktop](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/tableau-desktop) | [looker-studio](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/looker-studio) |
| [powerbi-embedded](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/powerbi-embedded) | [tableau-prep](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/tableau-prep) |  |
| [powerbi-datasource](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/powerbi-datasource) | [tableau-api](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/tableau-api) |  |
| [power-bi-report-server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/power-bi-report-server) | [tableau-online](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/tableau-online) |  |
| [powerbi-custom-visuals](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/powerbi-custom-visuals) | [tableau-public](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/tableau-public) |  |
| [powerbi-paginated-reports](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/powerbi-paginated-reports) | [tableau-server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/tableau-server) |  |
| [powerbi-api](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/powerbi-api) |  |  |
| [powerbi-rest-api](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/powerbi-rest-api) |  |  |
| [powerbi-filters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/powerbi-filters) |  |  |
| [powerbi-datagateway](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/powerbi-datagateway) |  |  |
| [powerbi-gateway](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/powerbi-gateway) |  |  |
| [powerbi-mobile](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/powerbi-mobile) |  |  |
| [powerbi-js-api](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/powerbi-js-api) |  |  |
| [powerbi-custom-data-connector](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/powerbi-custom-data-connector) |  |  |
| [power-bi-angular](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/power-bi-angular) |  |  |
| [powerbi-powerapps](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/powerbi-powerapps) |  |  |

Also, as noted in [Google's announcement](https://cloud.google.com/blog/products/data-analytics/looker-next-evolution-business-intelligence-data-studio):

> ...we acquired [Looker in 2020](https://cloud.google.com/blog/topics/inside-google-cloud/google-completes-looker-acquisition), and why we have big plans for the next few years.
> ...we are unifying our business intelligence product family under the [looker](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/looker) umbrella.

Thus the list of [looker](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/looker) tags is expected to keep increasing, with [looker-studio](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/looker-studio), [looker-studio-pro](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/looker-studio-pro) and [looker-google-cloud-core](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/looker-google-cloud-core) currently announced (also [google-looker-google-cloud-core](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/google-looker-google-cloud-core) would be counter-intuitive).

Answer (score 2):

Google Cloud approached us about synonymizing [google-data-studio](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/google-data-studio) to [looker-studio](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/looker-studio) and adding that, along with [looker](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/looker), to the [Google Cloud Collective](https://stackoverflow.com/collectives/google-cloud). The naming rationale outlined here by Nimantha was excellent guidance! The retagging is done and the tags are now part of the collective.